# How to fetch 0 or 1 entity with NSFetchRequest and fetchLimit = 1 from Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, try-catch, outofrangeexception

In a multi-language app I let users login via Sign In with Apple, Google or Facebook and then store their data (user id, given, last name, etc.) into `UserEntity`:

[image: UserEntity]

When creating an entity I set the `stamp` attribute to current epoch seconds.

Then in my custom view model I try to fetch at least one user with the following code and assign it to a `@Published var`, so that my app knows if the user has already logged in:

```
class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myUser: UserEntity?

    init(language: String) {
        fetchMyUser(language: language)
    }
    
    func fetchMyUser(language:String) {
        print("fetchMyUser language=\(language)")
        guard let container = PersistenceController.shared[language]?.container else { return }
        let request = NSFetchRequest<UserEntity>(entityName: "UserEntity")
        request.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \UserEntity.stamp, ascending: false) ]
        request.fetchLimit = 1
        
        do {
            myUser = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)[0]
        } catch let error {
            print("fetchMyUser fetch error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: please ignore the `language` String parameter ("en", "de" or "ru"). It is being used to select the corresponding `NSPersistentContainer`. This code works and is not related to my question.

My problem is that the `do/try/catch` code fails with `Fatal error: Index out of range` when there are no entities in the container yet (the user has never logged in):

[image: Exception]

Shouldn't `do/try/catch` just catch this exception, why does my app crash and how to fix my code, so that 0 or 1 `UserEntity` is fetched and assigned to `myUser`?

Comment: do/try/catch does *not* catch index-out-of-bounds errors. You have to check the count of the returned objects (or use `count(for: fetchRequest)`).

Comment: to avoid such error while accessing the first element, use (request).first instead of using (request)[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `do/try/catch` mechanism in Swift catches `Error`s which are `throw`n somewhere else, see [Error Handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) for the details. It is not a general exception handler mechanism.

In particular, “index out of bounds” is a *runtime error* and *cannot* be caught. It will always terminate the program immediately.

`viewContext.fetch(request)` throws an error if the fetch request could not be executed. Otherwise it returns an array or *zero or more* objects. In order to check if (at least) one object was returned, you have to check the `count` or `isEmpty` property of the return array.

Another option (as mentioned in the comments), is to use the `first` property, which returns an `Optional`: either the first element (if the array is not empty), or `nil`. In your case that would be

```
do {
    myUser = try container.viewContext.fetch(request).first
} catch let error {
    print("fetchMyUser fetch error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin, now it works. In my SiwftUI view, how could I check the @Published var for the fact that the user is logged in? I have tried `if userViewModel.$myUser != nil` but compiler says it is never null

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: I am afraid that I can not help you with that problem :( You could post a new question, I am sure that some SwiftUI experts know the answer.